# startActivityForResult from LiveWallpaper Service Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, live-wallpaper

I want the user to be able to tap on my livewallpaper to select an image from gallery. Is it possible to do this? To make this question more generic, how can we perform a startActivityForResult from a live wallpaper service?

I have gone through this thread - [Android liveWallpaper background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269991/android-livewallpaper-background) where startActivity is implemented. I'm specifically looking for a callback from startActivityForResult.

Thanks

Comment: You should look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679330/choosing-background-for-live-wallpaper

Comment: I know it's possible to do this by implementing the image picker through  a settings activity. I want the user to be able to pick an image by tapping on my live wallpaper.

Comment: I see. I am unsure about how to do that. 
Just a personal opinion: I would find it slightly annoying if I kept being asked for input every time I tapped my desktop.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to call **startActivityForResult** from any Service (including WallpaperService).
What you can do as a workaround is to create a transparent Activity:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
```

and invoke it from your LiveWallpaperService using **startActivity** (don't forget to set the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK).
Then you can use the **startActivityForResult** for doing your stuff and when managing the result you just have to **finish()** the transparent Activity.